# On solaris, is there a command to get the Ethernet Card MAC Address without being root

Tags: solaris, sunos

On Solaris, is there a command that I can run to get the MAC address of an ethernet card without running "/sbin/ifconfig -a" as root. Running /sbin/ifconfig -a as a non root user leaves out the MAC address - go figure!

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: You probably want [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try an `"arp -a"`, and look for your own hostname. (This works for me on the Solaris 9 machine I tried it on, but your mileage may vary.)

Comment: Or "arp $(hostname) | cut -d' ' -f4".

Comment: `arp -a` also only shows the *logical* interfaces.  If a link aggregation exists, it will show the aggregate, not the underlying multiple physical NIC devices.

Answer (score 16):

/usr/bin/netstat -pn |grep SP

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older question, but another option is:

```
/usr/sbin/prtpicl -c network -v
```

the `:local-mac-address` field will give you what you need.  You will also be able to pull up MACs for disabled interfaces.

You can identify the port by the `:instance` and `:driver-name` values.  I think this only works on SPARC platforms, and not x86 Solaris, but not certain.

Comment: This one shows unconfigured cards, but no card names. However, these can be extracted from :instance and :driver-name

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on my Solaris 11 x86 installation - I get no MAC addresses at all no matter what arguments I pass to `prtpicl`.

Answer (score 2):

Try "dladm" command with subcommand "show-phys" with -m option to see a list of MAC Addresses:

```
$ dladm show-phys -m
```

Comment: this is probably only working on Solaris 11 (not working on 10)

Answer (score 0):

```
dladm show-linkprop -p mac-address
```

is the [documented, definitive Solaris 11 answer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1458/geyqe.html) (as of Sep 2017):

> **Check the MAC addresses of all the interfaces on the system.**
>
> ...
>
> ```
> # dladm show-linkprop -p mac-address
> LINK   PROPERTY       PERM VALUE             DEFAULT           POSSIBLE
> net0   mac-address    rw   8:0:20:0:0:1      8:0:20:0:0:1      --
> net1   mac-address    rw   8:0:20:0:0:1      8:0:20:0:0:1      --
> net3   mac-address    rw   0:14:4f:45:c:2d   0:14:4f:45:c:2d   --
> ```

None of the other answers are guaranteed to return the actual MAC address of all NICs on Solaris 11.

On my Solaris 11 installation, `prtpicl` doesn't return any MAC address no matter what arguments I give it.

`arp -an` doesn't even show all the configured physical NICs:

```
Net to Media Table: IPv4
Device   IP Address               Mask      Flags      Phys Addr
------ -------------------- --------------- -------- ---------------
net2   224.0.0.251          255.255.255.255 S        01:00:5e:00:00:fb
aggr0  224.0.0.251          255.255.255.255 S        01:00:5e:00:00:fb
aggr0  192.168.1.92         255.255.255.255          60:6c:66:4f:c5:c7
aggr0  192.168.1.43         255.255.255.255          b8:88:e3:f5:4c:0b
aggr0  192.168.1.45         255.255.255.255          02:08:20:93:0b:d3
net2   192.168.1.35         255.255.255.255 SPLA     00:0e:0c:72:9f:6b
net2   192.168.1.1          255.255.255.255          70:f1:96:19:5b:88
aggr0  192.168.1.5          255.255.255.255 SPLA     00:14:5e:1b:14:0a
aggr0  192.168.1.4          255.255.255.255          00:1d:09:07:5a:93
aggr0  192.168.1.6          255.255.255.255          00:14:5e:2a:75:36
aggr0  192.168.1.25         255.255.255.255          00:11:25:90:d0:07
aggr0  192.168.1.251        255.255.255.255          00:c0:b7:d2:00:60
aggr0  192.168.1.244        255.255.255.255          00:10:75:07:55:94
net2   192.168.1.244        255.255.255.255          00:10:75:07:55:94
net2   224.0.0.22           255.255.255.255 S        01:00:5e:00:00:16
aggr0  224.0.0.22           255.255.255.255 S        01:00:5e:00:00:16
aggr0  192.168.1.151        255.255.255.255          4c:66:41:af:e8:fc
net2   192.168.1.151        255.255.255.255          4c:66:41:af:e8:fc
```

`netstat -pn` produces identical results.

`aggr0` is an aggregated link of `net0` and `net1`, which physically are `/dev/bge0` and `/dev/bge1`.  So what does `dladm show-phys -m` show?

`dladm show-phys -m` shows the MAC address of `aggr0` for both `net0` and `net1`, not the MAC address of the underlying physical NICs:

```
LINK                SLOT     ADDRESS            INUSE CLIENT
net1                primary  0:14:5e:1b:14:a    yes   aggr0-net1
vboxnet0            primary  8:0:27:4e:ea:4d    no    --
net0                primary  0:14:5e:1b:14:a    yes   aggr0-net0
net2                primary  0:e:c:72:9f:6b     yes   iprb0
```

Well, at least that does tell us that `aggr0` is an aggregated link using `net0` and `net1`, but the MAC address of both `net0` and `net1` is the MAC address of `aggr0`, not the actual physical NIC MAC address.

But `dladm show-linkprop -p mac-address` shows

```
LINK     PROPERTY        PERM VALUE        EFFECTIVE    DEFAULT   POSSIBLE
net1     mac-address     rw   0:14:5e:1b:14:a 0:14:5e:1b:14:a 0:14:5e:1b:14:b -- 
vboxnet0 mac-address     rw   8:0:27:4e:ea:4d 8:0:27:4e:ea:4d 8:0:27:4e:ea:4d -- 
net0     mac-address     rw   0:14:5e:1b:14:a 0:14:5e:1b:14:a 0:14:5e:1b:14:a -- 
net2     mac-address     rw   0:e:c:72:9f:6b 0:e:c:72:9f:6b 0:e:c:72:9f:6b -- 
estub0   mac-address     ?    ?            ?            ?         ?
aggr0    mac-address     rw   0:14:5e:1b:14:a 0:14:5e:1b:14:a 0:14:5e:1b:14:a -- 
vnic0    mac-address     rw   2:8:20:da:88:79 2:8:20:da:88:79 2:8:20:da:88:79 -- 
vnic1    mac-address     rw   2:8:20:31:af:de 2:8:20:31:af:de 2:8:20:31:af:de -- 
vnic2    mac-address     rw   2:8:20:fb:4:e7 2:8:20:fb:4:e7 2:8:20:fb:4:e7 -- 
vboxbridge0 mac-address  ?    ?            ?            ?         ?
samba/net0 mac-address   rw   2:8:20:93:b:d3 2:8:20:93:b:d3 2:8:20:93:b:d3 --
```

Using `awk` and `sort` to display just the default MAC address of each NIC:

```
dladm show-linkprop -p mac-address | grep -v LINK | awk '{ print $1 " " $6 }' | sort
```

produces

```
aggr0 0:14:5e:1b:14:a
estub0 ?
net0 0:14:5e:1b:14:a
net1 0:14:5e:1b:14:b
net2 0:e:c:72:9f:6b
samba/net0 2:8:20:93:b:d3
vboxbridge0 ?
vboxnet0 8:0:27:4e:ea:4d
vnic0 2:8:20:da:88:79
vnic1 2:8:20:31:af:de
vnic2 2:8:20:fb:4:e7
```

Note that the default MAC address of `aggr0` is the actual MAC address of `net0`/`/dev/bge0`, but that's only because when I created the aggregate link I didn't bother to assign a different MAC address and left it the default, which [per the `create-aggr` section of the `dladm` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/dladm-1m.html#scrolltoc) is selected from one of the interfaces that are part of the aggregation.